# File size doesn’t change after deleting part of appended object

Tags: append, data-blocks

I noticed while I was tidying up my blender file that an small object contains almost 300mb of data but it should really be about 3mb.

I think what I have done is that I have appended a large object and deleted 90% of the mesh but the remaining object seems kept the original file size.

Could it be possible? I have tried deleting materials, vertex groups, images but no changes in file size. I also tried file>clean up> unused xxx but no luck. The small object is still 300mb.

I was wondering if there was a way to delete the ghost like data from an object?

[image]

Comment: Try making the object and object data a single-user (object->relations->make SU -> object data) and do a clean up after

Comment: Otherwise I don't see how it could happen, appending creates a full copy of the object without reference to the original file. Are you sure nothing else in the scene can cause the large size? Please provide us with some screenshots for reference

Comment: Thank you very much! I’ll try this evening and upload the file.

Comment: Here is the link to download (https://we.tl/t-QksSFInZlc) Making the object data a single-user didn't seem to work. I has deleted some but hasn't changed the file size very much...?

Comment: I think I found something. The very original file which used Multiresolution modifier to sculpt could reduce the file size to 3MB by "convert to mesh" after "apply". However, the object was appended without "convert to mesh" in the .blend file (download link above). It seems impossible to use "convert to mesh" trick. Do you think there is a way?

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution.

Add Multiresolution modifier and click "delete higher" reduced all the expanded file size!